# Regex hangs on simple pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question, why this sample code hangs Regex in C# (.net core 2.0 and 4.5 full).

Are there any rules that say, that regex is too complicated. For me this should be rather simple case.

```
  var text = $"tenant/Modules/Orders/Events/d1d28f67-17f2-4a43-ac63-f5e4dcf6d36c";
  var validate = new Regex(@"^(\w+/?)+$");
  var test = validate.Match(text).Success;
```

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking as usual. Use  `@"^\w+(?:/\w+)*$"`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't know about non capturing groups. It makes sense.

Comment: The point is not about the non-capturing group, but making matching linear. The preceding quantified pattern should not match the same text as its adjoining quantified pattern.

Comment: Should your current regex match provided input string?